# How to use put method to update in database for Rest web service in play framework?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, playframework, playframework-2.1

I want to use rest web service to update the database and play framework is already rest service

what am i doing is:

i open a page that is **user info updation page**   and when user click on save button i want to save that values in database and rendering to web page that your information has been updated

my **view part**:

```
@(id: Long, userForm: Form[User])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
@main("EXTR Show"){


            <div class="container-narrow">


     <h1>Edit user info</h1>

    @form(routes.update.upd(id)) {

        <fieldset>
        @if(userForm.hasGlobalErrors) {
        <p class="error">
            <span><b>@userForm.globalError.message</b></span>
        </p>
    }

            @inputText(userForm("email"),'_label->"Enter email")
            @inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "user name")
            @inputText(userForm("password"), '_label -> "password")




        </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Save user" class="btn primary">
    </div>
    </div>
}
}
```

**controller part** is:

```
public static Result upd(Long id) {

        Form<User> u = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();

        if (u.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(editu.render(id, u));
        } else {

            u.get().update(id);

            User user = u.get();

            return ok(info.render(user));

        }
    }
```

**routes**:

```
GET  /update/:id                    controllers.signin.ed(id:Long) 

POST /update/:id                    controllers.update.upd(id: Long)
```

here in router i am using post to update that value but according top rest this is not good.

when i am using `put` at place of `post` it is giving error.

is it necessary to create ajax to use `put` method and if not how to use put method?

Comment: [Defining a `PUT` route should work](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting). If it doesn't, please [raise an issue with the devolopers](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues).

Comment: I can confirm that in play 2.1.3 the PUT verb doesn't cause an error for my app. Can you include the error message and stack trace?

Comment: it is telling that `get` request is coming